# Pug (Jade) mixin and if statement

Tags: pug, mixins

Well, I have objects in array named **data**:

```
[
 {
  title: 'Title',
  broadcast: true
 },
 {
  title: 'Title',
  broadcast: false
 }
]
```

On one page I want to show only ones with `broadcast: true` and I want to use a mixin call for that.
My mixin:

```
mixin techs(condition)
- var data = trs.tech.data;
ul.techs
    each item in data
        if condition
            li
              .h2= item.title
```

And my mixin call:

```
+techs('item.broadcast')
```

But (of course) this thing doesn't work as I want to. It shows all objects in array.
Is there any way to get result I expect without writing condition into mixin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, regarding this given problem, the mixin should not at all contain any additional logic connected to the data it receives. It instead should be a straightforward render method that iterates a list. Thus, in this case, the render method exclusively processes a list of already filtered/sanitized/proven data items, passed as this method's sole argument.

```js
// running, js only, demo code

var techList = [{
  title: 'Title',
  broadcast: true
}, {
  title: 'Title',
  broadcast: false
}];


function isMarkedForBroadcast(type/*, idx, list*/) {
  return (type.broadcast === true);
}


var broadcastItemList = techList.filter(isMarkedForBroadcast);

console.log('techList : ', techList);
console.log('broadcastItemList : ', broadcastItemList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
//- pug/view

mixin renderTechList(list)
    ul.techs
        each item in list
            li
                .h2= item.title

-
    function isMarkedForBroadcast(type/*, idx, list*/) {
        return (type.broadcast === true);
    }

+renderTechList(trs.tech.data.filter(isMarkedForBroadcast))
```

Comment: "The mixin should not at all contain any additional logic connected to the data it receives". Is this widely recognized best practice or personal opinion?

Comment: I do not know, whether it's widely recognized or not. But I'm willing to emphasize that experienced programmers over time come up with similar/same solutions. A pug mixin is just a specific render method. But as any method in any PL it will do one thing in time. It also will not work with data that is out of it's scope but with the data that is passed to it. Functions/methods that follow this approach are much more reusable; they are better readable and therefore can be easily maintained/refactored by other programmers. Thus, it very much reflects my strong opinion on this matter too.

Comment: Understood, thanks. Can you edit your question to clarify that is your opinion? Right now it reads as though you are stating it is syntactically incorrect to include logic in a mixin.

Comment: @sean ... done, changed the introducing sentence of my answer. Thanks for pointing to it.

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple issues with your code. Your mixin definition is `techs` but you are trying to call `tech`. Secondly the indentation is incorrect after the mixin declaration. Also, the array should be passed as an object with an identifier.

Therefore, consider restructuring your JSON onto,

```
{
  "tempArrayName": [
    {
      "title": "Title1",
      "broadcast": true
    },
    {
      "title": "Title2",
      "broadcast": false
    }
  ]
}
```

And your JADE/PUG could be rewritten as,

```
mixin techs
 - var data = tempArrayName;
 ul.techs
    each item in data
        if item.broadcast
            li
              .h2= item.title
+techs
```

Where `+techs` is the mixin call which can be reused in multiple places.
It checks for the condition usin `broadcast` value (hope that is what you are trying to achieve) and prints,

```
<ul class="techs">
  <li>
    <div class="h2">Title1</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Tested using - http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, thanks for your reply. I fixed the call in my question since I made this mistake only in the post. I was just wondering if it is possible not to write conditions in mixin tand as far as I can see it's inpossible.